# Where to register a BroadcastReceiver (Activity lifecycle fun)

Tags: android

Where's the right place to register/unregister an intent receiver in an Activity? Usually I would put stuff like this here:

```
class MyActivity 
{
    private BroadcastReceiver mMyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Do something.");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, new IntentFilter(...));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(mMyReceiver);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my activity can then no longer respond to the broadcast if it happens while it's in the pause state. Where's the right place to do something like this then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the following link might be useful to you

**http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-braodcast-receivers.html**

Comment: If I register the receiver in the manifest though, how would I get access back the instance of MyActivity though? The benefit of registering it in the activity class (I think) is that the supplied Context will be that of the activity which registered it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your case:

```
Unregister in onDestroy().
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, you can register the receiver in the onCreate() and unregister in the onDestroy().  This will keep it registered, even after it's been paused, until the activity is destroyed.

I had the reverse problem.  I had originally registered my receivers in the onCreate() and when my activity was paused, I still got logs that it was receiving broadcasts.  I moved it to the onResume, as you have, and that problem went away.