# C2DM unregister automatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm

I have an Android application that uses C2DM. I define the receivers in the main activity (not  in the manifest). I have something like this:

```
 c2dmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();

if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
  String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
  String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
  String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");
  System.out.println("receiver registration: " + registrationId);
  System.out.println("unregister aplicacion: " + unregistered);

  if (registrationId != null){
        saveConfig("key", registrationId);
    postC2dm(registrationId);
      }
}
else 
   if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
       final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
       System.out.println("Package : " + intent.getPackage());
       }
   }
 };
IntentFilter filtroReceiver = new     IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
filtroReceiver.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
filtroReceiver.addCategory("es.unizar.c2dm");
registerReceiver(c2dmReceiver,filtroReceiver,"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND",null);
```

In the Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
```

My problem is: When I receive "payload" through the intent "com.google.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE", I receive correctly the data "payload" but I receive a registrationId=null and my category is unregistered (in the action "com.google.c2dm.intent.registration").

The warnings that appears are:

Not granting permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND to package es.mypackage.es (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)

[DataMsgMdr] broadcast intent callback: result= CANCELLED for Intent {act=com.google.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat= es.mypackage.es (has extras)

Receiver package not found, unregister application es.mypackage.es sender sender@gm...

Thank you.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your account is not registered . are you sure , You entered the Correct `C2DM`
Registered account in your sender address .Use the Same `Package Name` that you Entered while Registering to `C2DM`...

Answer (score 1):

What I do not understand is why you do not define the broadcast receiver in the manifest. Defining it in the Activity means that C2DM only works when your application (specific) your activity is loaded (I assume your code is like [Where to register a BroadcastReceiver (Activity lifecycle fun)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980398/where-to-register-a-broadcastreceiver-activity-lifecycle-fun)).

But in that case you don't need C2DM, you could open an active connection to your server. The whole idea of C2DM is that it is able to trigger your application even when it is not loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943715/734687 for a guide.