# I want to access and launch broadcast receiver from an activity and do somthing

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app, in which I want to sent a message from the phone while making call.

The destination number is taken from the application database.

I have completed till that part, but I cant access the broadcast receiver in my activity:

```
public class PARENT_CALLActivity extends Activity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

String PARENT=null;
EditText edparent;
Button submit;
String parent_number;

public static final String BROADCAST = "sha.pcall.android.action.broadcast";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    edparent=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);


    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            PARENT=edparent.getText().toString();   

            MyDabasehandler db=new MyDabasehandler(getApplicationContext());

            if(db.getContact().equals(null))
            {
                db.addContact(new Contacts(PARENT));

            }
            else
            {
                db.editContact();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationUpdateReceiver.class);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

             finish();
        }

    });       
}

public class LocationUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        String outgoing_number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Toast.makeText(context, outgoing_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: where are you registering the broadcast receiver ?

Comment: how can i register and where i have to do that...?  can u plz explain that about

Comment: I will add an answer for this

Comment: I have posted an answer please check it out. I have a question you broadcast receiver is called LocationUpdateReceiver but onReceive() looks like an OutgoingCall Broadcast receiver.

Comment: ACTUALLY I LOOKING FOR OUTGOING CALL BROADCAST RECEIVER AND I JUST GIVE THE CLASS NAME LIKE LOCATIONUPDATERECEIVER.     AND THANK YOU FOR UR POST BUT I NOT GET WAT I NEED I AM POSTING MY NEW QUESTION ON HERE U PLEASE LOOK FOR IT

Comment: see the links (specially 2nd link) i provided in the answer... you need to register your receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a separate class by extending Broadcast receiver I suggest you do it in a separate Class file. If you only want to receive broadcasts as long as the activity is open create a private Broadcast receiver variable. like in this question:

[Where to register a BroadcastReceiver (Activity lifecycle fun)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980398/where-to-register-a-broadcastreceiver-activity-lifecycle-fun)

In latter case you can register the broadcast receiver variable with this method called registerreceiver.
[Here is the link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29)

It all actually depends on the requirements. If you want to receive broadcasts even if your app is closed (or the activity is not in the foreground), you need to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest file like this:

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.example.myapp.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is an example of google cloud message broadcast receiver. You also need to add intent filter, to specify which type of broadcast you want to receiver. In the above example the broadcast receiver can receive (see the intent-filter tag) two intents with actions:

```
"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"
```

and

```
"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"
```

After you are done with this you can accomplish your tasks in the overridden onReceive() method of broadcast receiver.

Hope this helps.